# LTS Enablement Stacks - Should I use quantal, raring or saucy?

Tags: updates, lts, 13.10, hardware-enablement-stack

I installed Kubuntu 12.04 from a beta ISO and I have been updating it ever since then. However, I want to opt into the hardware enablement stack for Precise now.

I have two questions:

First, how do I decide between versions? For example, betwen quantal, raring or saucy would I simply pick the latest? (And is saucy available for this purpose yet?)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy
```

Second, if I opt into the hardware enablement stack using the raring release, will there be any difficulties or challenges moving to the saucy or subsequent releases later? And what would I have to do at that time?

Comment: @Braiam-I installed 12.04 a long time ago! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice between quantal, raring and saucy is really up to you but these stacks are named after the release they feature in. As such, the saucy stack is currently unreleased and should be considered unsuitable for production.

Moving between stacks is possible. They're just packages, after all.

The only real bad scenario is starting on 12.04, installing 13.04's HWE and then upgrading the distribution to 12.10. Your X stack would be newer than the rest of the system in an untested configuration. I would recommend removing the HWE stack packages before upgrading.

Standard LTS upgrading (eg to 14.04) is fine though you may need to manually upgrade the HWE. I should also point out that come 14.04, the only two stacks supported for 12.04 are the original stack and 14.04's (which will continue to be supported for the remaining 3 years of 12.04's lifespan).

Comment: so I could install the HWE stack for raring now and when saucy is released I would `apt-get remove linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring` and `apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy`. Correct?

Comment: also, when 14.04 comes out, I plan to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04. I assume that if I have a HWE stack installed, I would need to remove it to do the upgrade to 14.04. Correct?

Comment: 1) If you wanted to upgrade to the saucy HWE stack, yeah. 2) I'm honestly not sure what the situation will be for big upgrades. I assume they'll be automatically removed by the installer but even if they're not, they'll be surpassed by 14.04's versions so shouldn't cause a conflict. It costs very little time to remove them before doing things so that might just be a safer method.