# Ubuntu 12.04 Not Detecting Ethernet Wired Connection

Tags: 12.04

I recently did a full install of *Ubuntu 12.04* (not a dual boot) on my laptop. In the past on my dual boot, I connected to a wired ethernet connection with no trouble at all.

Now, my laptop isn't detecting a wired connection when the cable is plugged in. I've tried restarting things and tinkering with files as suggested by other answers with no success.

```
lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: Your QCA8172 controller is [reported](http://askubuntu.com/q/342934/88802) to work correctly since 13.04. Try installing a more recent kernel using the [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) Ubuntu provides for LTS releases or upgrade to 13.10.

Comment: This sounds promising. I don't see why it's suddenly stopped working, but I'm a Linux noob who only has a year of experience. Could you elaborate a bit more about what this stack is? I've had a bad experience with upgrading in the past, so I'm pretty nervous about this whole thing.

Comment: Well, the Enablement Stack is a way to upgrade the kernel (and thus hardware support) without upgrading the whole OS. So this gives you the hardware support of Saucy (13.10) at the time of writing while keeping the 12.04.x stable userland software (well, except for Xorg, which has to be upgraded as well). Just read the document on the link I provided for details.

Comment: Awesome. That sounds...safer. I'm trying the Atheros driver fix suggested at the top (by you, I think). Fingers crossed.

Comment: @gertvdijk I think you suggested the solution for the Atheros driver fix and it worked!!!!! THANK YOU!

Comment: I want to discourage you to manually install drivers like compiling the `alx` driver by yourself. Really, just install packages and try a newer kernel first. It's easier now and easier to maintain. Compiling yourself is not the way to go if you're a beginner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the linked "Qualcomm Atheros AR8172 Driver fix? (lenovo g500s)" solution at the top. It worked perfectly on the first try.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to acknowledge here is there are [reports](https://askubuntu.com/q/342934/88802) about your specific network card being working out of the box since the Ubuntu 13.04 release. You could upgrade to 13.10 now or if you prefer, install a more recent kernel using the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). This installs a more recent kernel (and thus more hardware support) as well as a more recent Xorg graphical stack. The latter is not really of interest, but it does provide a fairly easy way to get more hardware support without upgrading to a more recent Ubuntu release.

See also:

- [What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/248914/88802)
- [LTS Enablement Stacks - Should I use quantal, raring or saucy?](https://askubuntu.com/q/340874/88802)